# Fixup git after a failed filter-branch --tree-filter

Tags: git, bitbucket

So I made a mistake. I had to remove an accidentally commited big binary file from git history and I used `git filter-branch --tree-filter` command to do so. And as a lot of threads here on SO states, it's a f.up if someone else commits to the branch while you are doing the filter-branch, I was mistakenly pulling those changes, merging them, then pushing to the remote, instead of doing a force push without merging. This mistake resulted in duplicated commits throughout my whole repository.

Is there any way to get rid of those duped commits. We have more than 10K commits, and those got duped so squashing them by hand, or doing anything by hand is not an option.

I also don't have anything in `.git/refs/original/refs` i don't even have this folder.

Can I still restore this repo, or do we need to start over?

---

Updates reflecting @ElpieKay

I made `git reset --hard` on the commit `(HEAD -> development) development@{2}: filter-branch: rewrite` this is the commit right before the wrong merge. This solved some issues but in our ongoing pull-requests numerous conflicts arised because of the newly introduced duplicated commits.

So I made `git push origin -f ad67a5z2z8:development` after which the HEAD pointed to the `ad67a5z2z8` commit which is the last commit before I issued the filter-branch command. After this, the conflicts in the pull-requests are gone, but the duplicated commits are still there. I couldn't remove those no matter what.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the branch is `master`. Run `git reflog master`. In the output you should be able to find one line from the top, which indicates where `master` was after `git pull`, in this pattern

```
b3c23d5 master@{n}: pull foo master: Merge made by the 'recursive' strategy.
```

and then another line following closely, which indicates where `master` was after `git filter-branch`, in this pattern

```
569a613 master@{n}: filter-branch: rewrite
```

And the line right below the above one indicates which commit `master` was before `git filter-branch`. It could be like

```
123abcd master@{n}: foo bar baz
```

Hashes are expected to be different in your repository. In the example, `569a613` is the very commit you should have force-pushed. You need to do 2 steps to fix the problem:

1) force-push `569a613` to update `master` in the remote repository,

```
git push origin -f 569a613:master
```

2) find out the extra commits pushed by others, and apply these commits to the new `master`,

```
git log --oneline 123abcd..b3c23d5^2
```

The commits listed in the 2nd step might not be accurate. Verify them with other contributors.

Comment: EplieKay thanks for the answer, I will definitelly try this, however I have a question beforehand. So from my understanding with filter-branch I rewrote the git history, will these steps also modify those and remove the duplicates? Mind, that I didn't accidentally commit something wrong and now I try to undo that commit, but I duplicated my commit snapshots for the whole repo and now I'm trying to remove the duplicates. No matter what, thanks for your answer

Comment: @Jim-Y To remove the duplicates in your local repository, `git checkout master; git reset 569a613 --hard` should work. It rolls the local `master` back to the state right before the wrong `git pull`. Note that the extra commits pushed by others are gone too. You can either apply those commits in the local repository and then push them, or ask their committers to apply them again after you force-push the new master.

Comment: @Jim-Y  And you need to inform other contributors that `master` has been rewritten, and they should force-update their local `master` carefully, otherwise they might mix the old master and the new one which results in the same situation with many duplicates.

Comment: I will get back to you and accept your answer, it seems to be working but I still need to test it throughoutly